# Hide icons in Android Studio and set Layout zoom to be 25% by default

Tags: android-studio

Is there a way to hide icons highlighted below in Android Studio? Also, is there a way to set layout Design view zoom to a specific value, say 25% by default. I did search the forum as usual but couldn't find specific answers. If there are already, would appreciate the link. Thank you.
Please note the second part of the image is rotated left by 90 degrees to minimize space. Android Studio 3.6.1 on Windows 7 Ultimate.
PS: I did try distraction free mode, even then some of these icons wouldn't go away.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Raised an enhancement request with Google, apparently they thought well of it. Seems its fixed per the tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155215268). Hopefully it will roll out in next release.